# How to execute a plugin script when a http request is addressed?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a plugin which performs some notification tasks.This works fine.
Now, I want to execute the main plugin script when a HTTP request is addressed.
That's here, I am a little confused:

My plugin source code is located in the classical WP plugin directory: 
/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin

And Here is the source of the main script that I want to be executed when an http request is addressed:

```
<?php
require_once('../wp-load.php');
require_once(ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/classes/Model.class.php") ;
require_once(ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/classes/MailNotifier.class.php") ;

$mailNotif= new MailNotifier('myadress@foo.bar');
$mailNotif->sendMailToRecipient() ;
?>
```

Actually, this script is located in: `WordpressRoot/script/main.php` this works, but I would like to remove it from the WP core files and only get files in my plugin directory.

I actually execute this script addressing the following http request: `http://example.com/script/main.php` but it was just for test purpose.

**What I want is to execute a main program located in my plugin dir using a http request. I tried to do a symlink but this is not allowed :**

```
ln -s /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/script/main.php script
```

How should I do this:

- Shall I wrote a webservice in wordpress (I am not really familiar with this)?
- Shall I use a redirection rule in wordpress?

What is the best way to do this proper?

Answer (score 0):

you can try as

```
$request = wp_remote_get('http://mydomain.com/script/main.php')
$theBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this note what I want to. I want to trigger the execution of my script only when a http request is adressed. I would like to move script/main.php under my plugin directory. I tried a symlink but this is not allowed.